# change data of push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I've been looking into cleaning up a test app's push notifications and I noticed that Facebook only uses one push notification for their messenger app.  For example if I get a 2 messages from a friend,  the app wont send two push notifications but will update the single push notification with the new message.  Are there any good tutorials on how to do this (I can't seem to find any) or does anyone have any example code I could take a look at?

Also,  for an app like facebook,  does the push notification carry any data to the app (ive heard this is bad practice)  or does the push notification just launch the app and the app refreshes any missed messages when it loads?

Answer (score 0):

Rate limiting the display of push notifications is better handled on the server side.  There is no mechanism or code you can put in your iOS app that would affect the rate at which notifications are displayed in the notification center (other than the binary support/not-support).

In the most naive implementation, you could do something in your backend that keeps track of the last time a push notification was sent, and refuse to send any more notifications until some interval later.  I'm sure Facebook has a more nuanced implementation of this, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question.

You should feel free to send custom data along with your push notification.  It is supported and not a bad thing at all.  You can only send small pieces of information though (i.e. do not expect to send the data to display an entire image) -- rather, you could be sending things like object IDs of referenced entities in your push notification.

For example, when Facebook sends you "XXX posted a photo", they're probably sending the userID and photoID along with the notification, so that the app knows which user/photo to display immediately when you tap the notification.